# Characterizing two even polynomials generating the unit ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in k[t]$ be two even polynomials, namely, each is a sum of even degrees monomials (including degree zero). $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.

Assume that we know that there exist another two even polynomials $A=A(t), B=B(t) \in k[t]$, such that $Af+Bg=1$.

> Is there something interesting that we can say about the exact form of $f$ and $g$ (involving their degrees, perhaps)?

**Example:** I have taken an arbitrary monic even $f$ of degree $4$ and an arbitrary monic even $g$ of degree $6$, and tried to solve $Af+Bg=1$, namely, to find the coefficients of $A$ and $B$ in terms of the coefficients of $f$ and $g$. Actually, I have taken $A$ and $B$ of small given appropriate degrees. Although we get linear equations, which are usually easy to handle, I am not sure how this helps in characterizing our 'original' $f$ and $g$ (their coefficients).

**Remark:** From $Af+Bg=1$ we get that there exists $h=h(t) \in k[t]$ such that $th= A'f+Af'+B'g+Bg'=0$, but I do not see how this helps.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Any such $f,g$ arise from composing a pair of relative prime polynomials with $t \mapsto t^2$.

Comment: Thank you. (I have noticed that observation, but did not see how it helps to find $f$ and $g$). Perhaps you are hinting that this is the best that we can obtain? (which is equivalent to asking for characterizing two arbitrary relative prime polynomials).

Comment: I think so. If you have polynomnials satisfying $(Af+Bg)(t) =1$ then make  $(Af+Bg)(t^2) =1$ and vice versa.

Comment: ok, thanks. I will try to think about additional conditions which, hopefully, may yield a more specific answer.